# Render a drupal_get_form() don't execute ajax select callback

Tags: forms, commerce, ajax

I want to re-use the commerce_customer_profile form in a particular context. To do this I use this :

```
function MY_MODULE_form($form, &$form_state, $profile_type) {
  $form = array();

  global $user;

  // Create new profile.
  $profile = commerce_customer_profile_new($profile_type, $user->uid);

  $form['customer_profile_' . $profile_type] = array(
    '#type' => 'container',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'class' => array(
        'field-type-new-' . $profile_type,
        'field-name-field-' . $profile_type,
        'field-widget-commerce-customer-profile')
    ),
    '#tree' => TRUE,
    '#parents' => array('customer_profile_' . $profile_type)
  );

 $form['customer_profile_' . $profile_type]['customer_profile'] = array(
    '#type' => 'value',
    '#value' => $profile
  );

  // Add the field widgets for the profile.
  field_attach_form('commerce_customer_profile', $profile, $form['customer_profile_' . $profile_type], $form_state);

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Save changes'),
    '#submit' => array('MY_MODULE_form_submit')
  );

  return $form;
}


function MY_THEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $args = arg();

  if ($args[0] == 'checkout' && !isset($args[2])) {
      $profiles = commerce_customer_profile_type_get_name();

      $vars['commerce_customer_profiles'] = "<div style='display:none'>";
      $vars['commerce_customer_profiles'] .= "<div id='commerce-customer-profiles'>";

      foreach ($profiles as $profile_type => $profile_title) {
        $vars['commerce_customer_profiles'] .= '<div id="customer-profile-' . $profile_type . '-ajax-wrapper">';
        $form = drupal_get_form('MY_MODULE_commerce_address_form', $profile_type);

        if (isset($form['customer_profile_' . $profile_type])) {
          $form['customer_profile_' . $profile_type]['commerce_customer_address'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['country'] = ajax_pre_render_element($form['customer_profile_' . $profile_type]['commerce_customer_address'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['country']);
          $vars['commerce_customer_profiles'] .= drupal_render($form);
        }

        $vars['commerce_customer_profiles'] .= "</div>";
      }

      $vars['commerce_customer_profiles'] .= "</div>";
      $vars['commerce_customer_profiles'] .= "</div>";
  }
}
```

Everything works fine except one and only thing: AJAX to select the country. The drupal_render() does not execute the form elements with an AJAX callback, despite the ajax_pre_render_element() on form item.

Any idea ?

Comment: preprocess functions only preprocess the variables after they have been rendered. Ajax requires a more earlier handling (because forms need to be cached, additional Javascript need to be added, etc).